How to implement custom beans in spring to replace beans injected in starter
I want to implement a custom spring boot starter and inject a custom Formatter using the @Enabler pattern.
@Import(FormatterAutoConfiguration.class)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EnableFormatter {
}
@Configuration
public class FormatterAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public Formatter jsonFormatter() {
        return new JsonFormatter();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingClass(value = "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper")
    public Formatter defaultFormatter() {
        return new DefaultFormatter();
    }
}

In the example above, they work fine. Now in the user's code, they want to define their own Formatter.
@Bean
public static Formatter myFormatter() {
    return object -> "this is my formatter";
}

Now there will be two Formatters in the beanFactory. I know this is caused by beanFactoryPostProcessors processing first, so I would like to ask if there is any way to achieve that when there is a user-defined Formatter, the bean in the starter will not be injected? @Enable mode cannot be changed.

Annotate second bean with @Primary

@Primary is feasible. Is there a way to register only user-defined beans?

Your config will always lead to 2 in this case. The defaultFormatter as that depends on an entirely different bean not being present. The jsonFormatter will be ignored but the myFormatter will then always be constructured. Hence in your override/replace sample you will always end up with 2 beans (and tha thas nothing to do with the BeanFactoryPostProcessor. To make it work your @ConditionalOnMissingBean should go on the @Configuration and check for a missing Formatter. If there is one the whole config will be iignored.

The problem is your configuration as it will always apply. In your sample case you will always end-up with 2 beans. The defaultFormatter as that check for a missing class, while the jsonFormatter checks for a missing bean.
In the case of the additional Formatter in your configuration the jsonFormatter will not be created but you will at least have the defaultFormatter simply because it checks on a missing class not a bean.
If you want to fix this move the @ConditionalOnMissingBean to the configuration and let it check for a missing Formatter. If there already is one the whole configuration will back off.
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(Formatter.class)
public class FormatterAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public Formatter jsonFormatter() {
        return new JsonFormatter();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingClass(value = "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper")
    public Formatter defaultFormatter() {
        return new DefaultFormatter();
    }
}

